# Vertical line artefacts in 2D lineplot

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, line-plot

I'm trying to create a 2D line chart with seaborn, but I get several artefacts as seen here, i.e. lines that suddenly shoot down or up with barely-visible vertical lines:
[image: borked lineplot]

Excel on the other hand produces a correct visualisation from the same file:
[image: correct lineplot]

My code follows the seaborn examples (a sample `test.csv` can be found [here](https://pastebin.com/cBcEnEw0)):

```py
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = pd.read_csv('test.csv')
sns.set()
lp = sns.lineplot(x=data['x'], y=data['y'], sort=False, lw=1)
plt.show()
```

Am I doing something wrong, or is matplotlib unable to handle overlapping values?

Comment: Use `plt.plot(data['x'].values, data['y'].values, lw=1)` instead. Meaning, matplotlib itself is perfectly capable of producing the desired plot.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest That's true, thanks! Can you post that as an answer? Seems to me like there's a bug in seaborn then.

Comment: No there is no bug. But a sns.lineplot by default is not meant to draw lines in 2D space. You can check the documentation and make sure to understand all parameters.

Answer (score 5):

By default, Seaborn calculates the mean of multiple observations of the y variable at the same x level. This behaviour can be disabled/controlled using the `estimator=None` parameter.

When adding this to the original code and data, we can observe that the artifacts are no longer present.

```
data = pd.read_csv('test.csv')
sns.set()
lp = sns.lineplot(x=data['x'], y=data['y'], sort=False, lw=1, estimator=None)
plt.show()
```

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lsFoR.png)

Answer (score 1):

It seems that in your data some points have the same x values. `line_plot` will see them as a single point with different samples, so it will compute the mean as the actual point and plot the error bar. The vertical artifacts are such error bars.

A hacky solution is adding a random tiny shift to your x values. In my case, I was trying to plot a PR curve and I encountered the same problem. I simply added an alternating shift to make sure there are no vertical segments:

```py
  precision, recall, unused_thresholds = sklearn.metrics.precision_recall_curve(
      y_true, y_pred)

  shift_recall = np.empty_like(recall)
  shift_recall[::2] = shift
  shift_recall[1::2] = -shift

  line_plot = sns.lineplot(x=recall + shift_recall, y=precision)
```

Before the fix:
[image: PR Curve with vertical artifacts]

After the fix:
[image: PR Curve without vertical artifacts]

Answer (score 0):

If you still want to use an `estimator` to aggregate while plotting rather than in the data, you can use `errorbar=None` to hide the vertical artefacts.

Something like:

```
plt.figure(figsize=(15,5))
sns.lineplot(
    data=df_sample,
    x='event_year_month',
    y='incidents',
    hue='person_id',
    palette='tab10',
    estimator='sum',
    errorbar=None
)
plt.xticks(rotation=90)
plt.show()
```

Passing `estimator=None` hides the error bars but also [plots all the data points](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.lineplot.html), which might not be what you want, rather an aggregation along the abscissa. Tested on 0.13.2.