# How do I increase the line thickness for sns.lineplot?

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, line-plot

I have a few seaborn lineplots and I can't figure out how to increase the width of my lines.

Here is my code

```
#graph 1
sns.lineplot(x="date", y="nps", data=df_nps, ax=ax1, label="NPS", color='#0550D0')
sns.lineplot(x="date", y="ema28", data=df_nps, ax=ax1, label="EMA28", color='#7DF8F3')
sns.lineplot(x="date", y="ema7", data=df_nps, ax=ax1, label="EMA7", color='orange')

#graph 2
dfz_nps_lineplot = sns.lineplot(x="date", y="nps", data=dfz_nps, ax=ax2, label="NPS", color='#0550D0')
dfz_nps_lineplot = sns.lineplot(x="date", y="ema28", data=dfz_nps, ax=ax2, label="EMA28", color='#7DF8F3')
dfz_nps_lineplot = sns.lineplot(x="date", y="ema7", data=dfz_nps, ax=ax2, label="EMA7", color='orange')

#graph3
dfp_nps_lineplot = sns.lineplot(x="date", y="nps", data=dfp_nps, ax=ax3, label="NPS", color='#0550D0')
dfp_nps_lineplot = sns.lineplot(x="date", y="ema28", data=dfp_nps, ax=ax3, label="EMA28", color='#7DF8F3')
dfp_nps_lineplot = sns.lineplot(x="date", y="ema7", data=dfp_nps, ax=ax3, label="EMA7", color='orange')

# formatting

plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 46, accepted):

As you can see from [seaborn.lineplot](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.lineplot.html) documentation, the function accepts matplotlib.axes.Axes.plot() arguments, which means you can pass the same arguments you can to matplotlib function [in this documentation](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.plot.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.plot).

If you want to simply adjust the width of your lineplots I find this the easiest: pass an argument `linewidth = your_desired_line_width_in_float` , for example, `linewidth = 1.5` in your `sns.lineplot()` functions.

You can find additional possible arguments in the documentations linked.

**Example output on random data:**

*seaborn.lineplot() without linewdith argument provided*
[image: searbon.lineplot() without linewdith argument]

*seaborn.lineplot() with linewidth = 3*
[image: seaborn.lineplot() with linewidth = 3]

Answer (score 11):

For those of you who are drawing **vertical** lines and wondering why changing the `linewidth` parameter seems to have no impact, the answer lies in lineplot's `estimator` parameter.

For example,

```
sns.lineplot(
    x=[1,1],
    y=[1,2],
    linewidth=10 # <- This will have NO impact
)
```

produces

[image: a graph with a thin vertical line]

While

```
sns.lineplot(
    x=[1,1],
    y=[1,2],
    estimator=None,
    linewidth=10 # <- This will now have an impact
)
```

produces

[image: a graph with a thick vertical line]

The [documentation](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.lineplot.html) states "by default, the plot aggregates over multiple y values at each value of x and shows an estimate of the central tendency and a confidence interval for that estimate".  The thin line is an artefact of that aggregation.  And by setting `estimator` to `None`, "all observations will be drawn."

For more discussion, see the question [Vertical line artefacts in 2D lineplot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58242950/vertical-line-artefacts-in-2d-lineplot)

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify the linewidth parameter = desired width

Answer (score 0):

```
sns.lineplot([data], linewidth = __ )
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**